# Using Bigquery , how to use conditional statement involving dates

Tags: google-bigquery

I require a column which counts the number days i.e(Order Date - 01Jan2020).

**Condition is** -> if Order Date lies between 01Jan2020 and 31Mar2020
then (DATE_DIFF('2020-01-31' ,Order Date,  DAY))
else 0
Question -> how to use this condition statement in BigQuery ?

**Table** -
Customer ID  | Order Date
298          | 2020-02-28
78           | 2020-04-02
31           | 2021-01-09
345          | 2021-09-09
74           | 2020-01-20

I tried -

```
if((Order Date <'2020-01-01') and (Order Date >'2020-03-31'),(DATE_DIFF('2020-01-31' ,Order Date,  DAY)
,0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try SELECT statement with WHERE clause:

```
SELECT id, orderdate, DATE_DIFF('2020-01-31', orderdate, DAY) as datediff FROM `yourdataset.ordertable`
WHERE orderdate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-31';
```

Output:

```
id  orderdate   datediff
298 2020-02-28  -28
74  2020-01-20  11
```

CASE statement:

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  orderdate,
  CASE 
      WHEN (orderdate BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-31') THEN DATE_DIFF('2020-01-31', orderdate, DAY)
      ELSE 0
END AS `datediff`
FROM `yourdataset.ordertable`
```

Output:

```
id  orderdate   datediff
78  02/04/20    0
298 28/02/20    -28
345 09/09/21    0
31  09/01/21    0
74  20/01/20    11
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below syntax: Once able to run it. Replace current_date with Order_Date. Hope this will work.

```
select 

if(current_date <'2020-01-01' and current_date >'2020-03-31' ,DATE_DIFF('2020-01-31' ,current_date,  DAY),0);
```

[image]